# Jquery filter() not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using simple filter function for my `GridView`
(I copy paste exact Code from tutorial and have checked syntax with sharpLinter .. )

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=grdRows.ClientID%> tr")
            .filter(":odd")
            .css("background-color", "grey");
});
```

Head Section

```
<head runat="server">

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

GridView Markup

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdRows" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" 
                    InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FUllName" HeaderText="FUllName" 
                    SortExpression="FUllName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" 
                    SortExpression="Gender" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Firebug shows me this JavaScript error

> TypeError: $ is not a function

When I `console.log` grdRows.ClientID has No Value

Similar Posts :

1. [Jquery selectors - filtering ASP.NET gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520047/jquery-selectors-filtering-asp-net-gridview) (it was about checkbox in Grid)
2. [Complex jQuery filter() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427563/complex-jquery-filter-not-working)

What is wrong with my code?

---

**Update:** I have already added scripts in the head section

Comment: do you added the JQuery refrence tag in  <head> tag?

Comment: I have added scripts already head section

Answer (score 1):

There are so many potential problems / un-necessary things in your code. First things first.

> TypeError: $ is not a function

means that either you have not added the [reference to the jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js) or you have a [conflict with another library](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) that uses `$` for another purpose.

---

Once, you resolve that error, lets come back to your code. Here we are using `asp:GridView` which has an [`AlternatingRowStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Instead of that jQuery filter, you only  need to write this in the Markup

```
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gray"/>
```

Now, if you want to use a class for your `:odd` row, do this

```
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grdRow_odd"/>
```

Now your JavaScript becomes,

```
$("#<%=grdRows.ClientID%> tr.grdRow_odd")
        .css("background-color", "grey");
```

or a much simplified

```
$(".grdRow_odd").css("background-color", "grey");
```

Whichever framework you use, always remember that *framework is your friend*.

Comment: i understand the rest you said .. i was actually trying to code a simpler filter operation for Grid

Comment: ok. please answer these questions. 1. are you using any other libraries? 2. which browser are you testing with? 3. whats the version of your jquery?

Comment: i am not using other libraries except the posted ones. I am using firebug lite on firefox

Comment: ok. the firebug > net panel > GET jquery-1.7.1.min.js is returning 200 OK?

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: $ is not a function` means that you don't include jQuery file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problev could be in your aspx code. Filter works http://jsfiddle.net/sZ9s5/. 

Try to clean and rebuild solution. Also you can try to use ClientMode='Static' for your grid and then select it $('#grdRows tr').

besides inspect generated HTML-code using FireBug or Chrome console

Comment: it says 403 Forbidden

Comment: Can you provide generated html?